# problems uv map and texturing with "shape keys"

Tags: animation, uv-image-editor, shape-keys

[image]i' not able to texturize correctly the new faces that appear from the mash using "Shape keys". For exemple if i have a cube and i animate the extrusion, the new lateral faces that appear don't follow the same uv map of other beginner faces. So the effect is terrible. 
To explane me better i insert the [LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16poV8BO0PEcux5lI0WpgsOgShapMzHy6) of a simple project to undertend. Thanck you!

Comment: I don't know if you can fix this, maybe try with a procedural texture? pr something else than shape keys?

Comment: Procedural texture is an idea but i want use an image texture. So the problem remane :(

Comment: so maybe you should use another method, like different meshes for your pilons and use bones to animate

Comment: Thak you to your Answer. Yes is True, but i try a faster method to do this, is strange that Blender lose UV Map of news faces. I Thick that existe a method using nodes to resolve this. .